# Are .cpp files useful?

Tags: c++

I can understand that headers are used to include classes and functions into another file, but .cpp just seem a bit useless to me.
.h files are used to declare functions that can be exported/imported, however, template functions and classes must be defined in the same .h file and not only declared.
I have only used .cpp files as of now for the main program, but can they be used for any other thing? I am using .h files for everything and just .cpp files for the `int main()` function

Question: What are the cases where you use .cpp files over .h files

Comment: While that might work on a trivial sized program, it doesn't scale. Build times go way up if you keep slamming everything into headers. You want each `.cpp` to contain the implementation code, and the corresponding `.h` to contain the definitions needed for other code to use it. Changes made within a single `.cpp` file require compiling *one* file. With your approach any change to *any* file requires recompiling *everything*.

Comment: @tadman But classes and structs must be implemented on ```.h```, at least that's what I read. I am making a library to export a lot of classes, so I am putting each one in a separate ```.h``` file. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Only in special cases like template functions or classes. The best way is have a `.h` that describes the class, and a `.cpp` that *implements* the class functions, if it has any. If you stick with this method you'll have quick compile times and, as a bonus, it will mesh with existing C++ code-base practices so other people can work with your code if necessary. This is critical if you work on teams.

Comment: class functions can be implented in a separate file? I know that you can make functions outside of the class using ```::``` operator, but I thought that wouldn't be correct

Comment: It's inherited from C. But in C++20 we'll be moving to [modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/modules-cpp?view=msvc-160).

Comment: @JHBonarius *Finally*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how to organize your code. Define headers for any classes you're using, like:

```cpp
// example.h
#pragma once // Avoid duplicate imports, if supported by your compiler
#include <string>

class Example {
public:
  Example();
  Example(const char* name);
  ~Example();
protected:
  std::string name;
};
```

Then *implement* it:

```cpp
#include "example.h"

Example::Example() {
}

Example::Example(const char* name_) : name(name_) {
}

Example::~Example() {
}
```

Then in `main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "example"

int main() {
  Example e("Some Name");

  return 0;
}
```

This will all change for the better when [modules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/modules) become the best way to declare things, but until then, this is how it's typically done.

Comment: When are modules going to come out? I am making a program but if modules are going to come out soon I can wait, since it isn't anything important

Comment: It's a C++20 thing, so soon, but it's good to know the regular style here since all non-trivial C++ code adheres to it in some form.